# Audit Trail Trigger generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, audit-trail

Working on Audit Trail system and decided to do it with Shadow/History table with triggers.

Followed this [Audit Trail Article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml) and trying to use [CodeSmith Generator tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10063/CodeSmith-generated-Audit-Log-Triggers)

I dont understand how it creates the history table and the trigger.

Is any one could understand how it works and help me on it.

I tried google to understand it. But there is no clear example

Nothing is clear with the below to me

Audit Table looks like this

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[<%= AuditTableName %>] (
    [ChangeLogID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1)  ,
    [OperationType] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL ,
    [ChangeTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [MadeBy] [varchar] (6)  NOT NULL ,
    [TableChanged] [varchar] (50)  NOT NULL 
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Detail Table looks like this

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[<%= AuditFieldTableName %>] (
    [FieldName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL ,
    [ChangeLogID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [BeforeValue] [sql_variant]  NOT NULL ,
    [AfterValue] [sql_variant] NOT NULL 
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

***How to generate this and add trigger and how can i insert AuditFieldTableName values?***

Comment: Partial answer: "*How to Generate this..?*"  You take out the comment markers ('-- ') and execute the commands.  I have taken out the comment markers for you.  You probably need to put specific table names in also.

Answer (score 0):

As we have  different types of columns in multiple tables, the audit table that you have specified wouldn't really suffice the cause. I suggest the following audit table:

```
TABLE auditEntry (
    auditEntryId           INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY,
    operationType          VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,      -- For INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE
    changeTimestamp        DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    madeBy                 VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    tableName              VARCHAR(30)  not null,      -- stores the name of the table changed
    columnName             VARCHAR(30)  not null,      -- stores the name of column changed
    oldInt                 INTEGER,
    newInt                 INTEGER,
    oldVarchar             VARCHAR(100),
    newVarchar             VARCHAR(100),
    oldDate                DATETIME,
    newDate                DATETIME)
```

Now I think it's a cakewalk for you to write row level triggers for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on your tables, if you have working knowledge of writing them. Search MSDN on how to write such triggers and you will be fine.

Comment: The `sql_variant` columns in the original Detail table takes care of the datatype problem.